# Relay contacts temporarily have resistance after closing

Tags: relay, resistance

The relays that I am using are JS1-12V-F.

The relays are being used on a testing apparatus to automatically test PCB components for accuracy.

When powered off for a long time (> 3 minutes), the resistance between Common and the Normally Closed leg is ~0 Ω (0.3 Ω). When powered on, the resistance between the Common and Normally Closed leg is ~infinity Ω (O.L.). If the power is kept on for 120 seconds (2 minutes) and then it is powered off, the resistance 1 second later will be > 10 Ω (as high as 60 Ω I've seen). The resistance will decay over a few seconds to maybe a couple minutes.

If the power is kept on for only a few seconds, then the resistance might only be as high as 3 Ω, but when there are 4 relays in series, the component being measured can be much higher than it truly is. For instance, an 82 Ω resistor will read 94 Ω and be considered bad. Or a 70 Ω bad resistor will read 84 Ω and be considered good.

Is anyone familiar with this phenomenon? Google has not been very helpful. I searched "relay temporarily has resistance when closing" and similar searches, but they weren't very helpful

Comment: Are you testing the relay alone, not connected to any circuit?

Comment: How much current flows through the relay contacts when they're closed? Does your relay have a [Wetting Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current) spec?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. The purpose of the relays is to switch between different first party resistors. But I have been specifically testing the relays (which are on a 3rd party PCB) without the first party resistors

Comment: Normally-closed contacts are generally less reliable than normally-open, since the return spring operation can be quite leisurely, in comparison to the slamming action when the NO contacts close, which helps to punch through any contaminants.

Comment: @brhans I believe that the DMM that I am using sends 1mA when measuring the 82 Ohm resistor. I could not find "wetting current" or "fretting" in the data sheet. I do not think that it was even taken into account when it was designed.

Comment: @jayben good point about the reliability of NC, but it shouldnt take multiple seconds to get close to 0 Ohm, right? I shouldnt be able to watch my fluke display show 10, 5, 3, 2, 1.5, etc... right?

Comment: It's the same as the "Min switching capacity" spec which Andy referred to in his answer.

Comment: @brhan ah, Thanks!

Comment: Why not use  REED relays? Must be used vertically, if I remember well. Max current limited, however. https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=90f597a4-145e-4edb-9d88-f1089b9e38ce&filename=littelfuse-reed-relays-he3300-datasheet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [JS1-12V-F](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1685559.pdf) just isn't good enough for low current applications such as testing PCB components. You need a relay with a specified operating contact current that can be as low as 100 μA (or even lower). For instance the JS1-12V-F has a minimum switching current of 100 mA at 5 volts i.e. no good for sensitive or low current circuits: -

[image]

You shouldn't skimp on test equipment relays because it's more trouble than it's worth. The best relays are hermetically sealed but, you will probably get away with an [OMRON G5 relay](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5v2.pdf): -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info. Maybe I will be allowed to make one with good components.

Comment: I cant find the minimum switching current for this relay is it "failure rate"? https://components.omron.com/us-en/datasheet_pdf/J117-E1.pdf

Comment: @Zeno that's because it ain't suitable. Don't skimp. If you need a high current relay that works at 10 uA and 16 amps then use two relays. The spec indicates that contact resistance is measured with 1 amp flowing (top of page 3 and note 1) and that is a massive indicator that it isn't suitable for microamp switching. I did mention G5 relays and not G2 relays.

Comment: Gotcha, I, not trying to skimp. It's not coming out of my pocket. I'm just trying to find the right ones that are active and in good enough supply

Answer (score 2):

Could you use an opto-MOS photocoupler? [Here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TLP241A_datasheet_en_20200217-1075431.pdf) is one for about a dollar that has less than 100 mOhms ON resistance and can handle 2A at 40V. However, it does not have a NC contact. You can get an [AQW612](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/AQW612EHAX?qs=wKtUvITRiakexYdlEluPqA%3D%3D) with one form A and one form B, but they are about $6, and have about 1 Ohm ON resistance. But as the ON resistance is known and consistent, you can just subtract it from the reading.

Comment: Off-state leakage current doesn't appear to be specified for item 1. Item 2 is hard to get to the data sheet. I also suspect that parasitic capacitance of both items might be a show-stopper for many in-circuit tests.